# PropertyChanged for an extended class

Tags: wpf, mvvm

My VS2015 solution consists of two projects: DataModel and DesktopClient.
DataModel has a Customer class - thats an EntityFramework 6 DB entity. Customer has a FirstName property.
In DesktopClient there is an extended class CustomerExt.
In DesktopClient, is it possible to have a notification to CustomerExt.FirstName changes? Defining a partial Customer across two projects won't work - DataModel is compiled first and it won't have partial properties defined in DesktopClient.

```
public class CustomerExt : Customer, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            this._isChecked = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't EntityFramework generate classes that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: No, for some reason I dont have it (DataModel is not my build), and can't override ... maybe thats what I should check

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand, you want update the View  when your date is updated on the database?

You have to find a way to request this information from your ViewModel.

some kind of RefreshFirstNameAsync

```
private string _firstName;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set
    {
        this._firstName= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName"); // There is better ways to implement that line
    }
}

private void RefreshFirstName(){
 FirstName = _userRepo.GetFirstNameAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if your base class does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged the safest way is to just write a wrapper class and only use that in your software. You can fit this in with your CustExt, or make it separate if you feel you want the extra layer.

*This also assumes that while you may not control the Customer class, you control all of the code creating/editing the Customer instances*, so that you can use this new class instead, then convert it to the original Customer class only when needed (such as a database transaction).

```
public class CustomerExt: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Customer _customer = new Customer();

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            this._isChecked = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    #region WrapperProperties

    public bool FirstName
    {
        get { return _customer.FirstName; }
        set
        {
            _customer.FirstName= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public Customer ToCustomer()
    {
        // returning a copy of the _customer instance here is safer than returning
        // the reference, otherwise the properties could be altered directly
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    ...
}
```

Some of this gets a little easier if you have an ICustomer interface and that is used during the database calls, then you can skip the formality of retaining a Customer instance.

I remember there being some third party libraries that have tried to automate this process - but I have never tried them and/or didn't trust them to work properly.